# Best methods for implementing push services from Azure to Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, push-notification

I have a Windows Service that will be constantly waiting for a notification to do work.

All I can find in MSDN is how to set up push notifications for Store apps and mobile devices.

Is there a technology that would allow pushing to a Windows Service from Azure? The Windows Service will be running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using push services is not the greatest idea. Its really just meant for mobile and Win* store apps.

Look into using Azure Service Bus.

You could set up a queue and your windows service would just listen to that queue, and when it finds a message relevant to it, it will process it.